# Tuleap: mail configuration on CentOS

Tags: sendmail, tuleap, centos6.5

In order to evaluate [tuleap](https://www.tuleap.org/), I have made a full instalaltion on a fresh Centos 6.5.

The mail feature doesn't seem to work as expected, which is critical as it's the way to validate new account creation.

I have tried to edit the sendmail configuration, but I am still getting no output mail.

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail stop
cd /etc/mail  
vi sendmail.mc

dnl define('SMART_HOST', 'myserver.fr')

m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf  
/etc/init.d/sendmail start
```

Do you have any idea where to setup the mail?

Comment: What do the system logs show which is relevant to the sending of email? Please **[edit]** your question to indicate the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you are using sendmail. The recommended MTA to use with Tuleap is Postfix. It could be working with sendmail but if you want to avoid any possible configuration difficulties just install postfix, it is the way to go:

```
$ /etc/init.d/sendmail stop
$ yum remove sendmail
$ yum install postfix
```

-- Martin